# SWIG function with pointer struct

Tags: python, c, pointers, struct, swig

Im new using SWIG to wrapped C shared library.

I have problem to call a C function with Struct pointer in python.

My files:

**ST_Param.h:**

```
typedef struct {
       unsigned int* device_Address;
       ....
       ....
       unsigned int lock;
}ST_param_ST;      


unsigned char ST_Param_Initialize(ST_param_ST * ST_param, unsigned int device_Address);
```

**ST_Param.c**

```
......... Rest of file.............

unsigned char ST_Param_Initialize(ST_param_ST * ST_param, unsigned int device_Address){

    if(ST_param == NULL){
    .......... rest of funtion .......................

    return 0;
}
```

Within  ST_Param_Initialize I confirm that the pointer exists, if not believe

**ST_Param.i**:

```
/* File : ST_Param.i */
%module ST_Param

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "ST_Param.h"
%}




%include "typemaps.i" 
%include "ST_Param.h"
```

I compiled and generated a .so file good.
In python I can import a library but I cant call a ST_Param_Initialize because a need a ST_Param_ST * parameter:

[ST_param_ST * error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shqVY.png)

How can I do this?

Note: i cant modify a .c and .h file. Only a .i file.

A search in google but I dont  understand how to do it

Thanks 
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You do this essentially the same way you do it in C: You first create a `ST_param_ST` struct and then pass this to the initialization function `ST_Param_Initialize()`. Here is an example in Python, assuming your module is called `ex`:

```
>>> import ex
>>> ST_Param = ex.ST_param_ST()
>>> ex.ST_Param_Initialize(ST_param, 42)
```