# Swig and pointer problems (python)

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using Swig to generate a python wrapper for a DLL file. What I do is:

1. Generate the wrapper and loader file using `swig -c++ -python
   myfile.i`
2. Create a new DLL file, include myfile_wrapper.cxx and
   compile to _myfile.pyd.
3. Load the module myfile.py created by Swig in Idle and try to use it.

The interface file looks like:

```
%module myfile 
/* Make a test with cpointer - needed?? */
%include cpointer.i 
%pointer_functions(MyHandle, my_handle_p);
%pointer_class(int, intp);
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "MyFile.h"
}%
%include "MyFile.h"
```

The function looks like

```
 typedef struct tagMyHandle
   {
      void* reserved;
   } *MyHandle;

int OpenFile(const char *szPath, MyHandle* pFile); // pFile is an out parameter
int GetNumberOfItems(MyHandle hFile, int *pnNrOfItems); // pnNrOfItems is an out parameter
```

If I try to use this from Python I have to do like this:

```
import myfile
handle_p = myfile.new_my_handle_p()
myfile.OpenFile("Path", handle_p)
handle = myfile.my_file_p_value(handle_p)
num_items_p = myfile.new_intp()
myfile.GetNumberOfItems(handle, num_items_p)
num_items = num_items_p.value()
```

Am I using Swig incorrectly? It feels that it's a very cumbersome way to call the functions that are supposed to be wrapped for Python.

I would like to do something like:

```
result, handle = OpenFile("path")
result, items = GetNumberIfItems(handle)
```

I can't change the source code for myfile.h.

I'm looked at [input/output parameters](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn46), but do I have to define them for each output type? MyFile.h have hundreds of functions with different output types. And it only supports primitive data types, but most types in MyFile.h are not primitive types, but like the struct MyHandle.

I have looked at [SWIG function with pointer struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437615/swig-function-with-pointer-struct) and http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn18 as well, but without any good solution.

**Update 1**
After a lot of help, I've solved most problems, but I still have a few left that I don't understand.

**Problem 1:**

```
// For the out parameter, shouldn't be needed?
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) MyHandle* pOutParam (MyHandle h) %{
    $1 = &h;
%}

// For all others
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) MyHandle* (MyHandle h) %{
    $1 = &h;
%}

// For the return type
%typemap(argout) MyHandle* pOutParam (PyObject* o) %{
    o = PyLong_FromVoidPtr(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,o);
%}

%typemap(in) MyHandle %{
    $1 = reinterpret_cast<MyHandle>(PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input));
%}
```

and the code

```
int OpenFile(const char *szPath, MyHandle* pOutParam);
int DoSomething(MyHandle* pInParam);
```

`OpenFile` works like charm, but `DoSomething` still tries to return `MyHandle` instead of taking it as an in parameter, and I don't understand why. `%typemap(argout) MyHandle*` is only defined for `pOutParam`.

**Problem 2:**
I don't understand how to make the type map for something like

```
int GetFileName(char *szPathBuffer, int iLength);
```

how to create a char buffer and send that in, like I C:

```
char szBuffer[MAX_PATH]; GetFileName(szBuffer, MAX_PATH);
```

Maybe something together with `cstring_bounded_output` or should I do something like

```
%typemap(in) (char*, int) { 
    $2 = PyString_Size($input); 
    $1 = (char*) malloc($2 * sizeof(char*)); 
}
```

but where is it deallocated?

**Problem 3:**
What is the correct mapping for enum values. If I have

```
typedef enum tagMyEnum {
MyTrue = 1,
MyFalse = 0 } MyEnum;
```

and the function

```
int IsCorrect(MyEnum* pOutValue);
```

@Mark Tolonen:
Thanks for all help! I really appreciate it! I've learned so much new things about Swig!

Comment: Yes and no. This is just one way of using SWIG. You can create more advanced typemaps, which allows simpler interfaces, see e.g. how NumPy is wrapped using `numpy.i`. If you are not familiar with writing advanced typemaps, I can recommend the `%extend` feature, where the extensions are made in the target language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with a interface similar to what you want to illustrate using typemaps to redefine an interface:

**myfile.h**

```
typedef struct tagMyHandle
{
    void* reserved;
} *MyHandle;

int OpenFile(const char *szPath, MyHandle* pFile);
int GetNumberOfItems(MyHandle hFile, int *pnNrOfItems);
// Added this to free the allocated handle.
void CloseFile(MyHandle hFile);
```

**myfile.cpp**

A hack implementation of the header...

```
#include "myfile.h"

int OpenFile(const char *szPath, MyHandle* pFile)
{
    *pFile = new tagMyHandle;
    (*pFile)->reserved = new int(7);
    return 1;
}

int GetNumberOfItems(MyHandle hFile, int *pnNrOfItems)
{
    *pnNrOfItems = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(hFile->reserved) + 5;
    return 1;
}

// mirrors OpenFile to free the allocated handle.
void CloseFile(MyHandle hFile)
{
    delete reinterpret_cast<int*>(hFile->reserved);
    delete hFile;
}
```

**myfile.i**

```
%module myfile 

%{
#include "MyFile.h"
%}

// An input typemap for the an output parameter, called before the C++ function is called.
// It suppresses requiring the parameter from Python, and uses a temporary
// variable to hold the output value.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) MyHandle* (MyHandle h) %{
    $1 = &h;
%}

// An output argument typemap, called after the C++ function is called.
// It retrieves the output value and converts it to a Python int,
// then appends it to the existing return value.  Python will get a tuple of
// (return_value,handle).
%typemap(argout) MyHandle* (PyObject* o) %{
    o = PyLong_FromVoidPtr(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,o);
%}

// An input typemap that converts a Python int to a MyHandle*.
%typemap(in) MyHandle %{
    $1 = reinterpret_cast<MyHandle>(PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input));
%}

// This applies a pre-defined int* output typemap to all int* parameters.
%apply int *OUTPUT {int *};

%include "MyFile.h"
```

**Output**

```
>>> import myfile
>>> s,h = myfile.OpenFile('path')
>>> s,h
(1, 7706832)
>>> s,v = myfile.GetNumberOfItems(h)
>>> s,v
(1, 12)
>>> myfile.CloseFile(h)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like charm! Then I know how to solve my problem!

Comment: I have one problem left though! How to deal with something like GetName(char* buffer, int length) to fill the buffer and send back? Do I need a typemap for that as well?

Comment: I have one other problem. How to make this work OtherFunc(MyHandle* inParamaterCanBeNull). How to make that differ from when it's an out parameter?

Comment: Is it possible to have different typenames for different functions names for example? That could fix the problem.

Comment: For buffer/length, you can make typemap a that works with a pair of parameters. For input vs. output parameter, you can make the input parameter const to differentiate, or you can make a typemap that is only applied to a specific named parameter.

Comment: Thanks! If I use the output parameter name for both "%typemap(in,numinputs=0) MyHandle*  pOut" and "%typemap(argout) MyHandle* pOut", then the conversion for the input parameter doesn't exist. If I set it only on %typemap(argout), then the input parameter becomes a return type, which I don't understand since the first typemap is for an input parameter.

Comment: Make an typemap(in) with a different parameter name.

Comment: It's not possible to have one typemap(in) for pOut and one for all other parameter names (since they are many different names for the input parameters)?

Comment: Sure, you can have a general one that targets `int*` and another that targets `int* param` and another that targets `const int* param` if you want.  SWIG will use the most specific one it can.  If you have specific options you need to deal with, it's best to ask another question with your code attempt.

Comment: I've updated my original question to be able to write code since I don't know how to do it in comments..